# How to show user email in congrats notice message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise gem.

I want to change after sign up message to tell something like:

```
  We sent confirmation instructions to user@mail.com.
```

I want to change flash[:notice] message, which is showing after user sign up.

I know, that I can change text in devise.en.yml, but how I can add Ruby code in this file ?

**EDIT : When added .erb extension to devise.en.yml file and made it devise.en.yml.erb file and when I'm trying to use erb extension:**

```
      signed_up: '<%=current_user.email%>'
```

shows me nothing.

Comment: Try to use the erb-style output like <%= @user.name %>

Comment: Doesn't work. Also tried `#{<%= current_user.email%>}`

Comment: What about `%{current_user.email}` ?

Comment: @Andrew , no it is not correct.

Comment: try adding .erb processor to the file, devise.en.yml.erb

Comment: @Rodrigo Zurek , added, but failing to output current_user email(

Comment: @Rodrigo Zurek, `Signed in successfully%{=current_user.email}` and output is `Signed in successfully`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is right code for my question:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create       
   if resource.active_for_authentication?
    session["resource_email"] = resource.email  
    flash[:notice] = "#{resource.email} signed in  successfully.."  if is_navigational_format?
  ...
  ...
  end
 end
end
```